# Extract parameter values of a function passed into parameter of function

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing

I can access the parameter values passed into a function structured as named list with

```
compile_name <- function(first_name, last_name){
  paste(first_name, last_name)
}

create_project <- function(project_name,...) {
  print(as.list(match.call()))
}

create_project(project_name = compile_name(first_name = "first", last_name = "last"), more_stuff = "more")


[[1]]
create_project

$project_name
compile_name(first_name = "first", last_name = "last")

$more_stuff 
[1] more
```

Is there a way to resolve the parameters of the function passed in the parameter (here project_name) as well into a list. In the example above I end up with the function call in the form of a string in the list point for the project_name parameter. Like so:

```
 [[1]]
create_project

$project_name
  $first_name 
    [1] "first"
  $last_name
    [1] "last"

$more_stuff 
[1] "more"
```

Also, is there a way to check if a parameter contains a function to react to this inside of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
compile_name <- function(first_name, last_name){
  paste(first_name, last_name)
}

convert_call_to_list <- function(x) {
  if (is.call(x)) as.list(x) else x
}

create_project <- function(project_name,...) {
  first_pass <- as.list(match.call())
  second_pass <- lapply(first_pass, convert_call_to_list)
  setNames(second_pass, names(first_pass))
}

create_project(project_name = compile_name(first_name = "first", last_name = "last"), more_stuff = "more")
#> [[1]]
#> create_project
#> 
#> $project_name
#> $project_name[[1]]
#> compile_name
#> 
#> $project_name$first_name
#> [1] "first"
#> 
#> $project_name$last_name
#> [1] "last"
#> 
#> 
#> $more_stuff
#> [1] "more"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that checks to see whether any of its arguments is of type "language" (i.e., an expression), and if so, further checks to see if any of *those* arguments are functions:

```
my_function <- function(a, b) {
  args <- as.list(match.call())[-1]

  if (is.language(args$b)) {
    sub_args <- as.list(match.call(call = substitute(b)))
  }

  if (any(sapply(sub_args, is.symbol))) {
    print('found a sub-function!')
    print(sub_args)
  }
}

my_function(a = 10, b = my_function(1, mean))

[1] "found a sub-function!"

[[1]]
my_function

$a
[1] 1

$b
mean
```

Comment: That does not solve my problem. If I use my_function(a = compile_name(first_name = "first", last_name = "last"))  Then I get $a
compile_name(first_name = "first", last_name = "last") but not a list which resolve the parameters from compile_name

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply looking for `list(...)`?

```
create_project = function (project_name, ...) {
    lst = list(...)
    # do something with `lst`.
}
```